# Non-commutative integral extensions?

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, ring-theory, noncommutative-algebra

In Commutative algebra there is a notion of an integral extension: Let $P$ be a subring of $R$. Then $R$ is the integral extension of $P$ if each element of $R$ is a root of a monic polynomial with coefficients from $P$. Integral extensions have the following advantage: if $I$ is a maximal ideal of $R$, an integral extension of $P$, then $I\cap P$ is a maximal ideal of $P$.

My question:

Is there a similar notion for non-commutative (possibly unital) rings which gives a similar claim for maximal right/left ideals of the subring (say, *intergrally embedded*)?

Comment: As far as I know these are *normalizing extensions*.